# Suppress warnings when reading data

Tags: r, xlsx, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to suppress warnings when I read data.
It happens only the first time I'm calling the function but I launch my program in the command line, so I have warnings each time.

```
library('xlsx',character.only = TRUE)
data <- read.xlsx("test/Classeur1.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1", encoding="UTF-8")
```

I get this warning message :

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>   WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper (file:/C:/Users/frus73117/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/xlsxjars/java/poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar) to constructor com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SecurityManager()
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper
>   WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

I've tried some functions like :

```
data <- suppressMessages(read.xlsx("test/Classeur1.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1", encoding="UTF-8"))
data <- suppressWarnings(read.xlsx("test/Classeur1.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

But nothing changed.
Any help or suggestions would be seriously appreciated!

Comment: These warnings are not being thrown by `read.xlsx` (in which case `suppressWarnings()` would work), but from the underlying Java code. `capture.output()` *might* work ...

Comment: could you show us the file "Classeur1.xlsx" ?

Comment: I've tried this function, even `invisible(capture.output(...))` doesn't seem to suppress these warnings... The xlsx file is empty for testing, but it is the same result as a full file.

Comment: related: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/986

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try  `capture.output(type="message", ...)`. From `?capture.output`:

> Messages sent to ‘stderr()’ (including those from ‘message’,
>        ‘warning’ and ‘stop’) are captured by ‘type = "message"’.  Note
>        that this can be “unsafe” and should only be used with care.

Comment: I saw it in the documentation, but it doesn't work with this problem.

Comment: That's surprising/interesting. `type="message"` is supposed to capture text sent to stderr, but maybe it only captures text sent to stderr by R (and not by external, e.g. Java programs). Other than upgrading your Java installation (as suggested in some of the linked material in comments above), the only suggestion I have is to try a different XLS-reading package (e.g. `readxl::read_excel()` ...)